# What are the common sense SEO practices that aren't dodgy or crap?

Tags: seo

In SEO there are a few techniques that have been flagged that need to avoided at all costs. These are all techniques that used to be perfectly acceptable but are now taboo. Number 1:  Spammy guest blogging: Blowing up a page with guest comments is no longer a benefit. Number 2: Optimized Anchors: These have become counterproductive, instead use safe anchors. Number 3:  Low Quality Links: Often sites will be flooded with hyperlinks that take you to low quality Q&A sites, don’t do this. Number 4: Keyword Heavy Content: Try and avoid too many of these, use longer well written sections more liberally. Number 5: Link-Back Overuse: Back links can be a great way to redirect to your site but over saturation will make people feel trapped

Comment: Just a nitpick, but in HTML 4 and 5, closing a br tag isn't required or even recommended.  Since br has no content, it is assumed closed.

Comment: *“closing single tags like `<br />`”* – How should that have any influence? Using semantic markup is a factor but using XHTML over HTML isn’t.

Comment: <br> is completely valid HTML. In fact, <br /> is invalid in HTML.

Comment: So with all this in mind - does anyone know if Google deducts points for deviating from the DOCTYPE?

Comment: I have started writting some guidelines and tutorials here: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/seo-guidelines-and-checklists.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google has the best [tools for webmasters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en), but remember that they aren't the only search engine around.  You should also look into Bing and Yahoo!'s webmaster tool offerings ([here are the tools for Bing](http://www.bing.com/webmaster); [here for Yahoo](https://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/mysites)).  Both of them also accept sitemap.xml files, so if you're going to make one for Google, then you may as well submit it elsewhere as well.

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is very useful for helping you tweak this sort of thing.  It makes it easy to see the effect that your changes are having.

Google and Bing both have very useful SEO blogs.  [Here is Google's](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/).  [Here is Bing's](http://www.bing.com/community/blogs/webmaster/).  Read through them--they have a lot of useful information.

Meta keywords and meta descriptions may or may not be useful these days.  I don't see the harm in including them if they are applicable.

If your page might be reached by more than one URL (i.e., www.mysite.com/default.aspx versus mysite.com/default.aspx versus www.mysite.com/), then be aware that that sort of thing sometimes confuses search engines, and they may penalize you for what they perceive as duplicated content.  Use the [link rel="canoncial"](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) element to help avoid this problem.

Adjust your site's layout so that the main content comes as early as possible in the HTML source.

Understand and utilize your robots.txt and meta robots tags.

When you register your domain name, go ahead and claim it for as long of a period of time as you can.  If your domain name registration is set to expire ten years from now rather than one year from now, search engines will take you more seriously.

As you probably know already, having other reputable sites that link to your site is a good thing (as long as those links are legitimate).

I'm sure there are many more tips as well.  Good luck!

Comment: How does a search engine know when your domain name is going to expire? Just curious.

Comment: The expiration date for a domain name is visible in the WHOIS record for that domain name.

Comment: And I guess the search engines have access to that en masse? As opposed to the rest of us who have to go through a captcha.

Comment: True that meta keywords isn't important, but meta description is often used as the description on the SERP so it is very important to include. It's one of the key drivers of click through off the SERP and onto your page.

Comment: Just a reminder that [google recently said they don't use meta description for ranking.](http://www.reversedelta.com/info/blog/google/official-google-ignores-keyword-meta-tag-and-does-not-use-description-for-ranking) It looks nice below the title, though.

Answer (score 11):

Content, Content, CONTENT! Create worthwhile content that other people will want to link to from their sites.

Comment: For what it's worth I agree content is king, but so is making sure you've done everything in your (ethical) power to make sure search engines can find it, and track how well they do. Which is why I accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to having quality content, content should be added/updated regularly. I believe that Google (an likely others) will have some bias toward the general "freshness" of content on your site.

Also, try to make sure that the content that the crawler sees is as close as possible to what the user will see (can be tricky for localized pages). If you're careless, your site may be be blacklisted for "bait-and-switch" tactics.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't implement important text-based
>   sections in Flash - Google will
>   probably not see them and if it does,
>   it'll screw it up.

[Google can Index Flash](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/06/google-learns-to-crawl-flash.html). I don't know how well but it can. :)

Comment: In my limited experience, not very well. Especially if you're not using Adobe Flash and instead are using a lesser expensive tool, like SWiSHMax. There's "compilers" out there to inject Google readable text but that's another lame hack.

Mainly I don't want to do Flash sites and the SEO excuse is a good one

Answer (score 1):

A well organized, easy to navigate, hierarchical site.

Comment: This doesn't help anyone or doesn't give any useful information...

Answer (score 0):

There are **many** SEO practices that all work and that people should take into consideration. But fundamentally, I think it's important to remember that Google doesn't **necessarily** want people to be using SEO. More and more, google is striving to create a search engine that is capable of ranking websites based on how good the content is, and solely on that. It wants to be able to see what good content is in ways in which we can't trick it. Think about, at the very beginning of search engines, a site which had the same keyword on the same webpage repeated 200 times was sure to rank for that keyword, just like a site with any number of backlinks, regardless of the quality or PR of the sites they come from, was assured Google popularity. We're past that now, but is SEO is still , in a certain way, tricking a search engine into making it believe that your site has good content, because you buy backlinks, or comments, or such things.

I'm not saying that SEO is a bad practice, far from that. But Google is taking more and more measures to make its search results independant of the regular SEO practices we use today. That is way I can't stress this enough: write good content. Content, content, content. Make it unique, make it new, add it as often as you can. A lot of it. That's what matters. Google will always rank a site if it sees that there is a lot of new content, and even more so if it sees content coming onto the site in other ways, especially through commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Common sense is uncommon. Things that appear obvious to me or you wouldn't be so obvious to someone else.

SEO is the process of effectively creating and promoting valuable content or tools, ensuring either is totally accessible to people and robots (search engine robots).

The SEO process includes and is far from being limited to such uncommon sense principles as:

- Improving page load time (through minification, including a trailing slash in URLs, eliminating unnecessary code or db calls, etc.)
- Canonicalization and redirection of broken links (organizing information and ensuring people/robots find what they're looking for)
- Coherent, semantic use of language (from inclusion and emphasis of targeted keywords where they semantically make sense [and earn a rankings boost from SE's] all the way through semantic permalink architecture)
- Mining search data to determine what people are going to be searching for before they do, and preparing awesome tools/content to serve their needs

---

SEO matters when you want your content to be found/accessed by people -- especially for topics/industries where many players compete for attention.

SEO does not matter if you do not want your content to be found/accessed, and there are times when SEO is inappropriate. Motives for not wanting your content found -- the only instances when SEO doesn't matter -- might vary, and include:

#### Privacy

When you want to hide content from the general public for some reason, you have no incentive to optimize a site for search engines.

#### Exclusivity

If you're offering something you don't want the general public to have, you need not necessarily optimize that.

#### Security

For example, say, you're an SEO looking to improve your domain's page load time, so you serve static content through a cookieless domain. Although the cookieless domain is used to improve the SEO of another domain, the cookieless domain need not be optimized itself for search engines.

#### Testing In Isolation

Let's say you want to measure how many people link to a site within a year which is completely promoted with AdWords, and through no other medium.

#### When One's Business Doesn't Rely On The Web For Traffic, Nor Would They Want To

Many local businesses or businesses which rely on point-of-sale or earning their traffic through some other mechanism than digital marketing may not want to even consider optimizing their site for search engines because they've already optimized it for some other system, perhaps like people walking down a street after emptying out of bars or an amusement park.

#### When Competing Differently In An A Saturated Market

Let's say you want to market entirely through social media, or internet cred & reputation here on SE. In such instances, you don't have to worry much about SEO.

Answer (score -1):

Go real and do for user not for robots you will reach the success!!

Thanks!